# Pinia action delayed changes

Tags: vue.js, pinia

Anyone knows how to achieve result on this case? Seems like `this` in delayed function is not reactive.

```
state: () => ({
  test: 'test',
}),
actions: {
  testAction() {
    const fn = () => {
      this.test = 'changed!'
    }
    setTimeout(() => {
      fn()
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?  The action works ok in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-euclid-mzclvh?file=/src/App.vue).

Comment: @yoduh https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ds2c4x?file=stores%2Fcounter.ts,pages%2Findex.vue

Comment: You left out the key info that this is SSR executed code... [Vue reactivity is disabled during SSR](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/ssr.html#writing-ssr-friendly-code). the created lifecycle hook of a component runs on the server side but does not have access to the DOM which is why it can't reactively update the UI.  if you remove the `if(process.server)` statement the function will run on both server **and** client allowing reactivity to work again.

Comment: ok, you're right. I have a 2nd question: is it possible to use node worker threads in pinia actions on server request?